# How to send argument to a contained component?

Tags: java, zk

I have a `.zul` file `index.zul`. It contain another `.zul` file `Prueba1.zul`. I am using zk7.

```
    <window border="normal" title="Test Send Argument" apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer"
            viewModel="@id('vm') @init('com.test.ControladorPadre')">
        <include type="@load(vm.mapType)" src="Prueba1.zul"/>
....
    </window>
</zk>
```

and

```
<zk>
  <window border="normal" title="Controlador 1" apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer"  zclass="z-window-popup"
         viewModel="@id('vm') @init('com.test.Controlador1')" >
        <button onClick="@command('doSort')" type="button" label="BT1" />
  </window>
</zk>
```

They apply different view-models. I want to sent arguments back from `Prueba1.zul` to process to display in `index.zul` and process in class `ControladorPadre`.

I have tried and searched without success. I currently only know that one way is to use `BindUtils.postGlobalCommand`. I am not sure if this is a good way to process or whether there exist another way to resolve my problem.

Comment: `postGlobalCommand` is a perfectly fine way to pass data between view models. Remember you can also do `onClick="@global-command('doSort')"` as per the [documentation](http://books.zkoss.org/zk-mvvm-book/8.0/data_binding/global_command_binding.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is a some solutions

First one is passing your first viewmodel to the second viewmodel.

Documentation [of @init](http://books.zkoss.org/zk-mvvm-book/8.0/syntax/databindinginit.html) says :

```
 viewModel="@id('vm') @init('org.zkoss.reference.developer.mvvm.databinding.InitVM', arg1='myValue')"
```

so in your case :

```
 viewModel="@id('vm2') @init('com.test.Controlador1', arg1=vm)"
```

If you look good, I changed the `id` of the second vm because you don't want to confuse your zul with the vm.
In `Prueba1.zul` the vm is also active and you can load (even save) data there.

Second one : save in vm and vm1.

```
<textbox value="@load(vm.someText) @save(vm.someText) @save(vm1.someText)"/>
```

Of course, sometimes you need to pass it after a command and this option would just not work then.

The Global-Command could do the trick,is in mine eyes the best solution, but don't forget **all active** viewmodels will be checked if that command exist, so make sure you make unique global-commands or you have some unwanted behaviour.

Comment: Nice answer. Thanks you so much for helping. I have applied it for my problem.